# URL in Referer header is detected as using multiple encoding

Tags: java, servlets, http-headers, owasp, esapi

Using owasp.esapi for to filter incoming request parameters and headers, I'm stumbling on an issue where apparently the Referer header contains a value that is considered as using "multiple encoding".

An example:

```
http://123.abc.xx/xyz/input.xhtml?server=http%3A%2F%2F123.abc.xx%3A7016%2Fxyz&o=1&language=en&t=a074faf3
```

To me though, that URL seems to be correctly encoded, and decoding it results in a perfectly readable and correct url.

So, can anyone explain the issue here, and how to handle this?

ESAPI reports the error when running this method on the header value:

```
value = ESAPI.encoder().canonicalize(value);
```

Output:

```
 SEVERE: [SECURITY FAILURE] INTRUSION - Mixed encoding (2x) detected
```

Answer (score 2):

As a matter of fact yes.  I fixed this bug in the upcoming release of ESAPI but it will require an API change, perhaps one that might have a bug based on your data here.

In short, prior to my fix, ESAPI just did a Regex against the URI.  The problem and slew of bug reports on this, is that URI’s are not a regular language.  They are a language themselves.  So what would happen is that the URI in question would have parameters that contained HTML entities, only, some random data variants would align to known HTML entities such as `&param=foo` which would be interpreted as the entity `&para;` which is paragraph. There were also some issues in regards to ASCII vs Unicode (non bmp encodings.).

At any rate there will be a new method to use in the release candidate for our next library, `Encoder.getCanonicalizedURI();`

This will be safe to regex against as it will be broken down and checked for mixed/multiple encoding.  The method you’re currently using is now deprecated.

Comment: I can't wait for it, so devised a solution with a custom encoder that does parse the HTML entities. When is that new version coming up?

Comment: We're trying to release now but are getting stuck with specific maven errors related to signing the library.  If you're interested in helping out, hit us up at esapi-project-dev@owasp.org

Comment: If you're interested in implementing a temp solution, the fully vetted method is here, line 482:  https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/blob/develop/src/main/java/org/owasp/esapi/reference/DefaultEncoder.java .  Keep in mind that the new release is an RC release due to the huge amount of changes that have ocurred since the 2016 release.  OH!  The group I told you to hit are google groups.

Comment: @StevenDeGroote I somehow missed your question.  The release went live June 24th of this year.